# Java Software testing

Tags: java, junit

I am revising for a test upcoming this week using previous exam questions and I just can't get 100% coverage, my program is :

```
public int computeInsurance(boolean SportsEquipment, boolean MusicEquipment)
{
int insurance;
if(SportsEquipment == true && MusicEquipment==true)
insurance = 20;
else if((SportsEquipment == true && MusicEquipment == false)||(SportsEquipment == false        && MusicEquipment == true))
        insurance = 10;
    else
        insurance= 5;

    return insurance;
}

}
```

I am using the following test cases:

```
public class Lab5CarTest {

@Test
public void testComputeInsurance() {
    Lab5Car t = new Lab5Car();

    int result = t.computeInsurance(true, true);
    assertEquals(20,result);

    int i = t.computeInsurance(true,false);
    assertEquals(10,i);

    int u = t.computeInsurance(false,false);
    assertEquals(5,u);


}

}
```

But I am missing 3 branches out of 8 in the else if line of my code!

Comment: Where's the `false, true` case ?

Comment: add "int i = t.computeInsurance(false,true);" and see what you get

Comment: Ahh i should have seen that one! But still after I add that line, I still am missing 2 branches out of 8 from my else if line of code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you test for:

```
int ip = t.computeInsurance(false,true);
assertEquals(10,ip);
```

Like this you should cover all.

you can simplify your code like this:

```
if (SportsEquipment && MusicEquipment)
    insurance = 20;
else if (SportsEquipment != MusicEquipment)
    insurance = 10;
else
    insurance= 5;
```

Comment: Ahh i should have seen that one! But still after I add that line, I still am missing 2 branches out of 8 from my else if line of code!

Comment: Try updating your if tree like Joop did show below. I did copy it to my answer to be complete.

Answer (score 0):

1 out of 4 (=2²) you are missing (not 2³), `t.computeInsurance(false, true);`

```
S M  I
------
t t 20
t f 10
f t 10
f f  5


if (SportsEquipment  && MusicEquipment)
    insurance = 20;
else if (SportsEquipment != MusicEquipment)
    insurance = 10;
else
    insurance= 5;
```